# Calculate Sum of Datetime in HH:MM:SS in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to calculate Sum in HH:MM:SS

First i am calculating datetime Difference in HH:MM:SS (works well)

```
Select  * 
Into    #_TicketType 
From    (    
        Select  *,
                convert(varchar(5), DateDiff(s, [Start Date] , [End Date] )/3600)
              + ':'
              + convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, [Start Date] , [End Date])%3600/60)
              + ':'
              + convert(varchar(5),(DateDiff(s,[Start Date] , [End Date])%60)) as [Ticket Type Time]
            ,
                convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, [Ticket Open Time]  , [Ticket Closed Time] )/3600)
              + ':'
              + convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s,[Ticket Open Time]  , [Ticket Closed Time])%3600/60)
              + ':'
              + convert(varchar(5),(DateDiff(s,[Ticket Open Time]  , [Ticket Closed Time])%60))[Total Call Time]
        FROM CTE
        )_A
```

Columns `[Start Date] , [End Date],[Ticket Open Time]  , [Ticket Closed Time]` of type `DateTime`

Further i want to calculate sum of it in HH:MM:ss

My Query :-

```
Select Distinct ATM,
    CAST (
          (SUM (datepart(hh, convert (varchar, [Ticket Type Time], 108)))
        + (sum (datepart(mi, convert (varchar, [Ticket Type Time], 108)))/60) ) 
    AS VARCHAR(2))
    + ':'
    + CAST (
          sum( datepart(mi, convert (varchar, [Ticket Type Time], 108))) 
        - 60 
        * (sum(datepart(mi, convert (varchar, [Ticket Type Time], 108)))/60)
    as VARCHAR(2))
    + ':' 
    + CAST (
          sum( datepart(ss, convert (varchar, [Ticket Type Time], 108))) 
        - 60 
        * (sum( datepart(SS, convert (varchar, [Ticket Type Time], 108)))/60)
    as VARCHAR(2))
From #_TicketType Group By ATM
```

It Gives me error

```
**Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 67
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.**
```

**Datebase SQL SERVER 2008**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant to convert to time (or datetime if your version of SQL Server doesn't support it), rather than varchar.

But, this is a very bad way to do this.  25:01:01 will not be a valid datetime.  You should sum up the seconds (as suggested in another answer), and then format the results as you like at the end.

So, in your first query, include another column that's the duration in seconds:

```
, DateDiff(s,[Start Date] , [End Date]) as [Ticket Type Seconds]
```

Then in the second query, just format the SUM([Ticket Type Seconds]), perhaps like this:

```
STR(SUM([Ticket Type Seconds])/3600) 
+ RIGHT(CONVERT(char(8),DATEADD(s,SUM([Ticket Type Seconds]),0),108),6)
```

That gives you the hours (that can be more than 24), concatenated with the ':MM:SS' part of the datetime that you get when you convert the seconds (added to the 0 date: 19000101 00:00:00) to datetime.

Comment: In HH:MM:SS format 25:01:01.... Will do for me as 25 is the sum of hours....how can I achieve the same ??

Comment: Sum the seconds (keep the seconds not the formatted times in your temp table, or keep both).  I'll add an expression in my answer...

Answer (score 2):

There are two related problems here.

1. SQL Server doesn't support Interval data types.
2. "8 o'clock" and "8 hours" are often written exactly the same--"8:00:00"--but they mean utterly different things.

---

You can't add values of type "DateTime".  Does "8 o'clock plus 3 o'clock" make sense? Nope.

Now, "8 hours plus 3 hours" makes sense, but *hours* aren't of type DateTime. In standard SQL, they're of type Interval. In systems that don't support the Interval data type--SQL Server is one of them--you have to calculate the differences in known units, like hours, minutes, or seconds. You can *easily* sum those kinds of values.

- Calculate the differences in seconds or minutes.
- Keep those values in your query.
- Sum the seconds or minutes.
- Treat the conversion to a nice, friendly display format (HH:MM:SS) as a separate step, or perhaps let the front-end application code do it.

That should eliminate some or all of the calls to convert(), and maybe even run faster.

Comment: +1 to "maybe even run faster" and to a great explanation. I say, use `cast` or `convert` sparingly. While they have their use in SQL Server, I don't think they should be used like that.

Comment: Can you please post sample query ??