# Convert HH:MM:SS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, time

I'm currently working on a call report however i've hit a snag. I need to calculate how long an agent has spent on the phone, the source data is in HH:MM:SS for the call duration. as in 1hr 12mins 10 seconds as appose to a number of seconds.  So if 2 agents had taken 2 calls the time spent would sum up for that day.

Is it possible to change this into seconds? or can anyone suggest something a but better?

Comment: Do have your code? or it needed to be created from the scratch?

Comment: Can you confirm the time columns datatype?

Comment: an example will help a lot

Comment: Is this SQLServer? (Date/time manipulation functions vary between RDBMSs.)

Comment: Many examples of this question appear here ---->

Comment: Is your source data's type varchar on database?

Comment: You can check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974856/calculate-sum-of-datetime-in-hhmmss-in-sql

Comment: Sorry, was pretty vague! its in sql2008. the data is being imported from a flat file so can change the columns data type on import and manipulate. I initially had it set to time but can changed that. Don't have any code as of yet.

Comment: DATEDIFF(ss, 0,  CAST('00:00:15' AS TIME))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If column type is `datetime` then:

```
(DATEPART(hh, @yourValue) * 60 * 60) + (DATEPART(mi, @yourValue) * 60) + DATEPART(s, @yourValue)
```

[Datepart reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

Comment: **`h`** doesn't seem to be a valid argument for the `datepart` method - @Gavlaaa did this work for you?

Comment: @ChrisMoutray yeah, typo. The valid is 'hh' or 'hour'. I like your variant more though

Comment: I'm probably bias but mine is more elegant :)

Comment: Gives incorrect result if time includes fractional seconds... Better to include in a term for DATEPART(millisecond, @yourValue)/1000.0

Comment: @EricKramer pls read OPs question; he states that data is HH:MM:SS and doesn't mention milliseconds. In the nicest way possible I don't think you should downvote answers because they don't fit your problem.

Answer (score 8):

**Time to Seconds**

Assuming it's a time datatype then you can change to seconds like this

```
DATEDIFF(second, 0, @YourTimeValue)
```

And here's a simple aggregation example (ie sum)

```
DECLARE @data TABLE (TimeColumn TIME)
INSERT INTO @data values ('01:12:10'), ('02:15:45')

SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, TimeColumn)) FROM @data
```

Which results in 12475 seconds

**Seconds to Time**

And I guess to complete the picture to convert back to time format from seconds

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, @TotalSecondsValue, 0) AS TIME)
```

or as part of the aggregation example

```
DECLARE @data TABLE (TimeColumn TIME)
INSERT INTO @data VALUES ('01:12:10'), ('02:15:45')

SELECT CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, TimeColumn)), 0) AS TIME) FROM @data
```

Which results in a time of 03:27:55

Comment: Gives incorrect results... Seems to truncate (versus round) seconds... For example '00:12:10.750' is converted to 730 seconds (when it should either be 731 or 730.750)

Comment: @EricKramer I haven't thought about this for many years - but i remember using this perhaps you need to datediff millisecond; ie `DATEDIFF(millisecond, 0, @YourTimeValue)`

Comment: @EricKramer pls read OPs question; he states that date is HH:MM:SS and doesn't mention milliseconds. His example 1hr 12mins 10 seconds and not 1hr 12mins 10 seconds 750 milliseconds. So your comment and downvote is incorrect for this particular question.

Answer (score -1):

Two approaches...

This first is concise and works fine when there aren't fractional seconds involved (which would be truncated vs. rounded by DATEDIFF):

```
select DATEDIFF(second, 0, '00:12:10')
```

This second approach extracts the various components of the time (including fractional milliseconds):

```
select
      DATEPART(hh, '00:12:10.750')*60*60) + 
      DATEPART(mi, '00:12:10.750')*60 + 
      DATEPART(s, '00:12:10.750') + 
      DATEPART(millisecond, '00:12:10.750')/1000.0
```

If your time precision is more granular than millisecond, you can alternatively use nanosecond resolution:

```
select
      DATEPART(hh, '00:12:10.750')*60*60) + 
      DATEPART(mi, '00:12:10.750')*60 + 
      DATEPART(s, '00:12:10.750') + 
      DATEPART(nanosecond, '00:12:10.750')/1000000000.0
```

Comment: why are you reposting the same answers as Artur and myself, and changing it to suit your problem? Which I presume is a rounding problem.